# Python pandas 日付の.str AttributeErrorエラーについて

Tags: python, pandas

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Ppython, Pandasを使って、A列に08の月が含んでいる日付だけフィルターしたいです。

ただ下記のエラーが表示されます。

```
raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
```

strからdtへ変換しましたがそれでも同じエラーが出ます。
08の日付形式を合わせないといけないでしょうか。

```
filter_A = df2['A'].dt.contains('08')
```

Excel data

```
A
2021-07-05 00:00:00
2021-07-15 00:00:00
2021-08-02 00:00:00
2021-08-03 00:00:00
```

code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\test.xlsx',sheet_name ='A')

# print(df) 

filter_A = df['A'].str.contains('08')
```

#### 補足情報（Python/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.9.5, Windows10の仮想環境で利用しています。

もしわかる方いれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `df['A']` は `datetime` 型なので、例えば「月」 を抽出する場合は `df['A'].dt.month` とします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。試してみましたが`Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike value`のエラーが表示されます。

Comment: `print(df.A.dtype)` を実行すると何が表示されますか？

Comment: `object`と表示されます。

Comment: 手元の環境で Excel データを作成して `read_excel` で読み込むと `datetime64` 型になります。それでは明示的に型を指定して読み込んでみて下さい。`df = pd.read_excel('C:\\test.xlsx', sheet_name ='A', dtype='datetime64') `

Comment: 上記で行うとこちらのエラーが表示されました。

`result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 379, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 611, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 753, in pandas._libs.tslib._array_to_datetime_object
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
TypeError: invalid string coercion to datetime`

Comment: `File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 534, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 257, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1374, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 649, in parse
    raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Ψ`

Comment: `Unknown string format: Ψ`が表示されるので、変な文字が入っているからでしょうか。

Comment: 「変な文字が入っているからでしょうか」 はい、そうなりますね。まずは Excel のデータを見直した方が良いかと思います。

Comment: `Ψ`の文字削除、`dtype: int64`になりましたが、今度下記のTypeErrorが表示されます。もしもしわかる方いれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです。

`Name: A, dtype: int64
filter_orderdate = df['A'].dt.month(8)
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`

Comment: `df['A'][df['A'].dt.month == 8]` とします。

Comment: 早速、上記の方法できました。いつもありがとうございます。

Comment: ただ上記の方法でフィルターを行う場合、B列、C列など表示されないです。表示させる方法ありますか。

Comment: 実際に確認していないので間違っていたらごめんなさいですが、`df[df['A'].dt.month == 8]` とすれば良いかと思います。

Comment: いえいえ、大丈夫です。問題なくできました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 度々、すいません。月を抽出の変数を作成しましたら、`df[df['A'].dt.month == month]`を指定しても何も表示されないです。原因わかりますでしょうか。

`#月を抽出
month= dt.now().strftime("%m").lstrip("0")
print(month)　
8`

Comment: おそらく型が違うのだと思います。`month = int(dt.now().strftime("%m").lstrip("0"))` として `month` を int 型にしてみて下さい。

Comment: すいません。。そういえば、int型でした。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 質問(行いたいこと) と, コメントの内容(現実) に, 段差が見られます。Python勉強してるようですが, excelのデータ云々より先に, Pythonの基礎 Pandasの基礎を, (本を読むなどして) 身につけたほうがよいのでは？
(語学留学すれば, 現地で日々接するので自然とペラペラに … というのは幻想で, 大抵は身につくことがないように,
基礎を学ぶことなく ここで質問していても, Pythonの学習にはなりません)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。基礎をしっかり学んでから質問いたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(解決しているようだけど, とりあえず回答として)

excel手元にないので CSV で行います

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
indx,num,date
AA,123, 2021.7.10
BB,246, 2021.8.10
CC,337, 2021.8.20
DD,312, 2021.9.10
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), index_col=0)
print(df.to_markdown()) # display(df)
```

| indx | num | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 123 | 2021.7.10 |
| BB | 246 | 2021.8.10 |
| CC | 337 | 2021.8.20 |
| DD | 312 | 2021.9.10 |

例えば, 数値データ (`num` 項目) を `str`型に変換すると,
(**`str`型に変換できたなら**) `str` accessor (アクセサ) を使用し, Pythonの `str`型に基づくメソッドが利用可能
[str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) も呼び出し可能

参考:

- (docs.python.org) [文字列メソッド](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)
- [pandas.Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)

> Patterned after Python’s string methods, with some inspiration from R’s stringr package.

以下, 上記データに基づく実行例

```py
# dtype は int64 なので数値型
print(df['num'])
# indx
# AA    123
# BB    246
# CC    337
# DD    312
# Name: num, dtype: int64

# 数値型なので四則演算可能
print(df['num'] *2)
# indx
# AA    246
# BB    492
# CC    674
# DD    624
# Name: num, dtype: int64

# 文字列型に変換し, .str accessor を使用
print(df['num'].astype(str).str.replace('2', 'Hey'))
# indx
# AA    1Hey3
# BB    Hey46
# CC      337
# DD    31Hey
# Name: num, dtype: object
```

また, `datetime64[ns]`型（`Timestamp`型）に変換すると,
`dt` accessor (アクセサ) を使用することで datetimeライクに扱える

参考:

- 'dt' accessor [pandas.Series.dt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)
- [pandas.Series.dt.month](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html)
- [datetime オブジェクト](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) の Class attributes に `month`などが含まれる

```py
# datetime64 型に変換し, 項目に割り当て
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(df['ts'])
# indx
# AA   2021-07-10
# BB   2021-08-10
# CC   2021-08-20
# DD   2021-09-10
# Name: ts, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# .dt accessor を使用し .month 属性にアクセス可能 (メソッドも呼び出し可能)
print(df['ts'].dt.month)
# indx
# AA    7
# BB    8
# CC    8
# DD    9
# Name: ts, dtype: int64

# 加工後の DataFrame
print(df.dtypes)
# num              int64
# date            object
# ts      datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object
print(df.to_markdown()) # display(df)
```

| indx | num | date | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 123 | 2021.7.10 | 2021-07-10 00:00:00 |
| BB | 246 | 2021.8.10 | 2021-08-10 00:00:00 |
| CC | 337 | 2021.8.20 | 2021-08-20 00:00:00 |
| DD | 312 | 2021.9.10 | 2021-09-10 00:00:00 |

---

質問にあるエラーは

> AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")

(意訳) 文字列であれば `.str` accessor (アクセサ) を使うことができる
⇨ (指定のオブジェクトが)文字列型でないことを意味する

> strからdtへ変換しましたがそれでも同じエラーが出ます。

どのように変換したか質問に記されていないけど
変換していないか, あるいは変換したけど結果を代入していないか … などの理由が考えられます